# Project Euler #8 in Java Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number

Tags: java

If I ran the below program it gives output as 40824 it is absolutely correct and expected.

```
public class EulerProblem8 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String thousandNumbers = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    int limit = 5, count = 0, prod = 1, large = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < thousandNumbers.length(); i++) {
        count++;
        if (count == limit) {
            count = 0; 
            if (prod > large) {
                large = prod;
            }
            prod = 1;
        }
          prod *= Integer.parseInt(thousandNumbers.charAt(i)+"");
    }
    System.out.println("Large no is :" + large);
 }
}
```

If I changed the code as below it gives,different output ? 31752 why ?

```
public class EulerProblem8 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String thousandNumbers = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    int limit = 5, count = 0, prod = 1, large = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < thousandNumbers.length(); i++) {
        count++;
        prod *= Integer.parseInt(thousandNumbers.charAt(i)+"");
         if (count == limit) {
            count = 0; 
            if (prod > large) {
                large = prod;
            }
            prod = 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Large no is :" + large);
}
```

}

Comment: What are you expecting as correct output?

Comment: @skiwi 40824 per the first line

Comment: 40824 is expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You are not considering every possible 5 digit number, but only every 5 digits starting from the forth, in the first case and in the second starting from the start.  The second case cuts the String up differently so gives a different answer.

Note: you can convert the character to a decimal much faster with.

```
prod *= thousandNumbers.charAt(i) - '0';
```

Comment: In fact, the first program only multiplies the first *four* digits to get the first product.  It thus is computing the products of digits 0-3 (wrong), 4-8, 9-13, 14-18 ..., while the second is computing the products of 0-4, 5-9, 10-14, 15-19, ... Neither program is correct.  The first program gives the correct answer purely by coincidence.

Comment: @ajb thank you for the correction, I had it the wrong way around.

Comment: @ajb yes I agree with you. But my doubt is why second computing fails it compute like 0-4,5-9 ? question is : **Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number**

Comment: @user1295079 You should be checking 0-4, 1-5, 2-6, and so on.  If you check only 0-4, 5-9, 10-14, ..., you will miss 80% of the products.  If you check only 4-8, 9-13, 14-18, ..., like in the first program, you will also miss 80% of the products.  The only reason this worked was that you got lucky and the answer was one of the 20% you didn't miss.

Comment: @ajb I got it you tell me to check like 0-4,1-5 instead of 0-4,5-9 right ?

Comment: @user1295079 yes, the problem simply says "find the greatest product of five consecutive digits", and that means you have to look at *all* substrings of five consecutive digits, even the ones that overlap other substrings.

Comment: @user1295079 You need to check 0-4, 1-5, 2-6, 3-7, 4-8 i.e. you have to consider every possible start point.